# Pandas date_parser with lambda

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to parse dates when importing csv file using a lamda expression but I am getting:

> `**ValueError: time data 'Date' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'**`

The dates in my file do not have zero padding.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

#Date format 1/1/2019
date_parser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y')

_2019 = pd.read_csv('2019.csv',names=[
                                        'Date',
                                        'Col2',
                                        'Col3',
                                        'Col4',
                                        'Col5',
                                        'Col6',
                                        'Col7'],
                                                parse_dates=['Date'],
                                                date_parser=date_parser)
```

Comment: I believe `%m` parses months with leading zeroes whereas you only have `1` not `01`. Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: @sshashank124 I tried %-m but that didn't work either

Comment: Hmmm yeah you're right, it seems the 0-padding is only relevant during formatting as a string, during parsing it accepts both

Comment: @sshashank124 It has something to do with the way I specified column names because it didnt rename my column instead created the 0 row with my column names I removed the column names and it worked fine I also reformatted my csv prior to importing

Comment: In that case voting to close this question as unreproducible

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with the way I specified column names because it didnt rename my column instead created the 0 row with my column names I removed the column names and it worked fine I also reformatted my csv prior to importing

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the `to_datetime` method of pandas itself to try converting the dates after they have been read in.